# Is there better way to write this logic to resolve `Prisma "UnknownJsonError","body":{"code":"P6004"`?

Tags: prisma, next.js13, next-auth

In my NextJs app, I am trying to verify user's registration right after signing up, but continue to get an issue related to `prisma`. The error states:

```
Error during sign-in: PrismaClientKnownRequestError: 
Invalid `prisma.user.findUnique()` invocation:

This request could not be understood by the server: {"type":"UnknownJsonError","body":{"code":"P6004","message":"The Query did not produce a result within the maximum allowed execution time of 10 seconds."}} (The request id was: 82d1136a29d9440b)
    at ni.handleRequestError (.../node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:124:6817)
    at ni.handleAndLogRequestError 
(.../node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:124:6817)
    at ni.request (.../node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:124:6817)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async l (.../node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:124:6817)
    at async handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/userSignin.js:31:34) {
  code: 'P5000',
  clientVersion: '5.6.0',
  meta: undefined
}
```

Here is the flow:

1. User signs up
2. An email with a token is sent to the user's email on file.
3. User clicks on a link to come back to the site, logs in.
4. Goes to the `newUser`'s page.
5. Paste the token, and clicks submit.

On submit, I ran a function that checks if the user already exists, and if `isVerified` is not `null`, and if the token matches the one that's already genereated and set for the user. If `isVerified` set to `true`, then the user is redirected to the `/dashboard`, but if it is null, but the submitted token matches,  then `isVerified` is set to `true`, then user gets redirected to the `/dashboard`; else the user is redirected to the `/login` page.

Here is the server code:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import { authOptions } from './auth/[...nextauth]';
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next';
import { withAccelerate } from '@prisma/extension-accelerate';

const prisma = new PrismaClient().$extends(withAccelerate());

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);

    try {
        const { email, verification } = req.body;
        const lowercaseEmail = email.toLowerCase();
        const trimVerification = verification.trim();

        console.log('session:', session);

        if (!email || !verification) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'An entry is missing' });
        }

        if (req.method === 'POST') {
            // Look for an existing user with verified status
            const existingUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
                where: {
                    email: lowercaseEmail,
                },
                cacheStrategy: { swr: 60, ttl: 60 },
            });

            if (existingUser && existingUser.isVerified) {
                // User already verified, log them in

                return res.status(200).json({
                    user: existingUser,
                    message: 'User has been verified',
                    redirect: '/dashboard',
                });
            }

            // Check for unverified user with matching email and verification token
            const unverifiedUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
                where: {
                    email: lowercaseEmail,
                    VerificationTokens: {
                        some: {
                            token: trimVerification,
                            expires: { gt: new Date() },
                        },
                    },
                    isVerified: null,
                },
                cacheStrategy: { swr: 60, ttl: 60 },
            });

            if (unverifiedUser) {
                // Update the user's verification status to true
                const updatedUser = await prisma.user.update({
                    where: {
                        email: lowercaseEmail,
                        VerificationTokens: {
                            some: {
                                token: trimVerification,
                                expires: { gt: new Date() },
                            },
                        },
                        isVerified: null,
                    },
                    data: {
                        isVerified: true,
                    },
                    cacheStrategy: { swr: 60, ttl: 60 },
                });

                return res.status(200).json({
                    user: updatedUser,
                    message: 'User is verified',
                    redirect: '/dashboard',
                });
            }

            return res.status(200).json({
                message: 'User is not verified',
                redirect: '/api/auth/signin',
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'There is an error' });
    } finally {
        await prisma.$disconnect();
    }
}
```

My `schema.prisma` is setup as such:

```
model User {
  id                 String              @id @default(cuid())
  userId             String?             @unique
  name               String?
  externalId         String?
  brandName          String?             @unique
  firstName          String?
  profileImage       String?
  password           String?
  image              String?
  lastName           String?
  isVerified         Boolean?
  provider           String?
  email              String              @unique
  createdAt          DateTime            @default(now())
  updatedAt          DateTime            @updatedAt
  profileId          String?
  role               Role                @default(MANAGER)
  emailVerified      DateTime?
  Accounts           Account[]
  VerificationTokens VerificationToken[]
}

model VerificationToken {
  id          String    @id @default(cuid())
  userId      String
  token       String    @unique
  expires     DateTime
  updatedAt   DateTime  @updatedAt
  user        User?     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  createdAt   DateTime  @default(now())
  activatedAt DateTime?

  @@unique([userId, token])
}
```

Can you help figure this out, why and how to resolve?